# F12: Go to definition doesn't work for Robot Framework: Add a path in the "Robot: Additional Environment Variables" setting

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, robotframework

I have MyTest.robot file and keywords.robot and keywords.py files in different Folder A and B.
When I try to find definition of a keyword in MyTest.robot (In Folder A), it shows nothing because it is located in B, for keywords in A it's OK they can be found.

I followed this to add path but is doesn't work

1. Open your Robot Framework file in Visual Studio Code.
2. Click on the gear icon on the left sidebar to open the Settings view, or press `Ctrl+,` (`Cmd+,` on macOS).
3. In the search bar at the top of the Settings view, type "Robot Framework".
4. Look for the setting named "Robot: Additional Environment Variables" and click on the "Edit in settings.json" link below it.
5. This will open the `settings.json` file with the Robot Framework extension settings. If the file is empty, add the following JSON code inside the curly braces `{}`:

```json
"robot.additionalEnvironmentVariables": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "C:/B"
}



I want to have all keywords available at F12 even they are located in different folders or repo
```

Comment: What extension are you using for Robot Framework? I am using Robot Code, and it does not use those settings.